Capitalise only first letter in list of symbols list using glossaries-extra package
I want to have the first letter of the list of "Symbols, Greek Letters, Sub- & Superscripts" also capitalised per default. With the acroym list "Abbreviations and Acronyms" it worked using
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

after \makeglossaries.
MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[nomain,toc,acronym,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of symbols}
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\loadglsentries{myglossaries_mwe}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall 
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations and Acronyms,nonumberlist,nopostdot,style=long]
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,title={Symbols, Greek Letters, Sub- \& Superscripts},nonumberlist,nopostdot,style=long]
\end{document}

This is the glossary file "myglossaries_mwe":
\newacronym{POX}{POX}{polyoxazolidinone}
\newacronym{HPT}{HPT}{high performance thermoplastic}
\newacronym{MF}{MF}{microfiltration}
\newacronym{UF}{UF}{ultrafiltration}
\newglossaryentry{nu}{name=\ensuremath{\nu},description={stoichiometric number},sort=x, type=symbolslist}
\newglossaryentry{Tg}{name=\ensuremath{T\textsubscript{g}},description={glas transition temperature},sort=x, type=symbolslist}



Your symbol list is added as a generic glossary, so the corresponding category is general rather than acronym.  Add
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

to your code.
There are built-in symbol-specific commands (see this answer) for which you would need
\glssetcategoryattribute{symbol}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

instead.

Thanks - your first option works perfectly!
